# Method takes no arguments

Tags: python

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def printName():
        print "my name is %s" % self.name

Mitchell = Person("Mitchell")
Mitchell.printName()
```

This code throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mitch/Desktop/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    Mitchell.printName()
TypeError: printName() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I'm sure I did this correctly...

Comment: Your missing the `self` parameter.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the indention. Your code is not valid Python.

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot to add `self` explicitly to printName instance method. It should have been like

```
def printName(self):
    ...
```

Python implicitly passes object instance to every instance method. Although not directly related to the question, try to use `pep8` conventions when you are working with Python. According to `pep8` function names are snake-cased not camel-cased and so are variable names. So use `print_name` and `mitchell' instaed of their camel and pascel-cased counterparts.

Comment: It cannot be a class method since it is using self.name :)

Comment: Sorry my fault. I failed to notice the instantiation

Answer (score 0):

you missed the self param in the `printName` function definition

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def printName(self):
        print "my name is %s" % self.name
```